# How to access global iframe object

Tags: javascript, iframe, window

when I'm inside iframe I can access global variable of the parent using `parent` like

```
parent.$('.selector').remove();
```

it will access jQuery of the parent and remove selector from dom. How can I do the same but from parent. To access iframe global object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it it's

```
$('iframe')[0].contentWindow;
```